# Sitecore - Webforms for Marketers 2.3 - Inserting a new form into a page

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm trying to insert a new form I created in Webforms for Marketers 2.3.  I go to the page I want to insert the form on, presentation tab, form, Insert.  I select the form I created but then get a message - "There are no allowed placeholders in order to insert a new form".

I then went to Layout-Placeholder Settings-Content and added Layout-Renderings-Modules-Webforms for Marketeres - Form.

No success.

I've also tried adding the form while it was and was not in the Webforms for Marketers restricting placeholders settings.

No success.

So, anyone know what I'm missing?  Do I need to add a specific sitecore placeholder in the sublayout to hold the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand upon Zach's answer.

I had not been binding the placeholder settings to the page correctly.  To do this I went to the Presentation tab and hit details.

[image]

I then went to the placeholder settings, and added a new entry here.

[image]

Make sure to enter the correct place holder where the form will be entered.  Then go and add the form on the page.  Once  you choose your form and have added the placeholder correctly, it should show up here.  (This was my original problem).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up which placeholders a form may be added to using the Restricted Placeholders window accessible from the Sitecore Desktop.

**Steps**

First, open the sitecore desktop and go to *All Applications* -> *Web Forms for Marketers* -> *Restricting Placeholders*:

[image]

Next, use the resulting window to configure the placeholders to which forms may be added. At least one of the selected placeholders must be present for you to add a form to the item.

[image]

I hope this helps. Good luck! :)

Comment: No problem, it's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another edge case where this dialog may fail to display your available WFFM placeholders.

If you have the [SSL Redirector](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/SSL_Redirector.aspx) module installed, and the form page in HTTPS mode, the dialog will fail to display the list of placeholders.

The solution is to modify the SSL Redirector to only perform redirection when `Context.PageMode.IsNormal` is true, and the current site name `!= "shell"`.