# "There are no allowed placeholders in order to insert a new form" error displayed

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm trying to add a form into a page but am getting the error `There are no allowed placeholders in order to insert a new form.`

A content placeholder exists within layout/placeholder settings (also copied to Devices - default) which has allowed controls of:
Sample Rendering
Form Interpreter.

However I still get [this error](http://www.ocvc.ac.uk/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/~/media/Images/Promotional%20material/select-a-placeholder.ashx?db=master&la=en&vs=1&ts=20131018T1103550837).

Can anyone help! Please note I am new to Sitecore so go gentle!

Comment: See my answer here for another possible cause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900109/sitecore-webforms-for-marketers-2-3-inserting-a-new-form-into-a-page/19147307#19147307

Answer (score 3):

Have you set up the placeholders correctly? In `Web Forms For Marketers` you can check this on `Sitecore->All Applications->Web Forms for Marketers->Restricting Placeholders`. 
Also make sure your item has those placeholders available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my comment to 'Sitecore climber' thanks.

Comment: Does the item you're trying to add it to have ContentColumn or Form Placeholder available though?

Comment: What do you mean by 'available'? Thanks

Comment: Does the item that you are trying to add the form on have access to those placeholders? As an example, say that ContentColumn is on ContentLayout. If the item you're trying to add a form to doesn't have ContentLayout, it will also not have ContentColumn, so you won't be able to add the form to that item.

Comment: The item I am trying to add the form to is a content page let's call it "content page" for clarity. How do I see if "content page" has access to those placeholders?

Comment: Easiest is probably go into design mode/ page editor mode and check if the placeholder is there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v2_reference_usletter.pdf) at page 7 :

> ***2.3 Restricting Placeholders Shown in the Placeholder List***
>
> The "Insert a New Form" wizard only allows you to add forms to placeholders that have "Placeholder Settings" items. Users that add new forms must have write access to those items to see placeholders in the Placeholder list. This allows developers and Web site administrators to define which placeholders 
>   may contain a form.
>
> The **Restricting Placeholders** application helps to restrict the list of placeholders shown in the **Placeholder list** of the **Insert a New Form** wizard.
>
> The **Selected** field lists the placeholders where users can add a new form. When you click the **OK** all the changes are saved.
>
> To add a placeholder to the **Restricting Placeholders All** list, you should create a new placeholder under the **Sitecore/Layout/Placeholder Settings** item. If you already have a placeholder, you would like to use, create a placeholder in with the same name under the Placeholder Settings item.
>
> **After installation, the module shows the Restricting** Placeholders application and users can select the placeholders they want to use. This application is also called through the Sitecore *\All Applications\Web 
>   Forms for Marketers\Restricting Placeholders* command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have set up the placeholders as follows: http://www.ocvc.ac.uk/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/~/media/placeholders1.ashx?db=master&la=en&vs=1&ts=20131018T1211370316 

I have also taken a screenshot of the allowed controls of these placeholders: http://www.ocvc.ac.uk/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Manager/~/media/placeholders2.ashx?db=master&la=en&vs=1&ts=20131018T1212260163

Again I am getting the same error message.